# Login for multiple roles and permission

Tags: php, laravel-5, backend, php-7

Hey I am making a project in which their are multiple users with different who are going to login. The users according to their role will be shown different pages. I have made a piece of code but whenever a user logins he/she can access the page of another user.

This is my login controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ( Auth::attempt(request(['email', 'password'])) ) 
        {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();

            if($user->is_admin()) 
            {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }

            return redirect()->route('home'); 
        }

        redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

These are my routes

```
<?php
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::post('/login/custom', ['uses' => 'LoginController@login', 'as' => 'login.custom']);
        Route::get('/login/custom', ['uses' => 'LoginController@login', 'as' => 'login.custom']);
        Route::get('/home', function() { return view('home'); })->name('home');
        Route::get('/dashboard',function(){ return view('dashboard'); })->name('dashboard');
    });
```

And this is my model

```
 <?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function is_admin(){
        if(!$this->admin)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no motivation to use `is_admin()` function instead of use `->admin` (only if is setted up as `Boolean` / `Tinyint` on the migration).

It returns `true` if `->admin` is `true` and viceversa...

Maybe your `is_admin` function doesn't works well as expected, and it always return the same value event if someone is an admin.

It also could a good idea include your `create_users_table` migration code in the question.

Take a look at: [laracasts episode about the authentication](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/13)